# SQL, Count statement

Tags: sql, select, syntax, count

```
select count(characterid) as num , schoolhouseid
from student natural join Character
```

Pretty much a beginner in SQL, trying to figure out why the count statement crashes the syntax.
it works without schoolhouseid and also without the count but together it crashes

Comment: How would you expect the result to look like? Count(characterid) will return one single value, while scoulhouseid will return a value for each row in the set. Perhaps you want to group by schoulehouseid?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag please.  It is sad that you are learning so-called "natural join" without understanding `on` or `using` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

well it depends what's your desired output, but it looks like you are trying to do this :

```
select count(*) as num , schoolhouseid
from student
group by schoolhouseid
```

which gives you number of rows you have in each schoolhouse